# Zero cells not show blank.

Tags: formatting

I am using Exel for Mac.  I have a simple formula and all cells with zero are showing as blank.  I inserted a row and it is now showing a 0.  It is frustrating.  Why would one cell not follow the rest of the spreadsheet?

Comment: 0 can be interpreted as blank depending on the cell format, make sure its formated for numbers. Not sure how to do that in Excel for Mac though.

Comment: What question are you looking for an answer to? Do you want the zeros to show as blanks? As zeros? Do you just want to know why they're different? Is just the inserted row showing as zero or did everything revert to showing the actual value? Is the value supposed to be zero? Are they formatted the same? What are the formulas? How are they formatted in each case? How do the zeros get into the inserted row? How do you want it formatted?

Answer (score 1):

Some Excel display formats show "-" or a blank when the value is zero. You can select "General" or another display format to have the value actually show up.

Comment: @fishingaddict's answer below is better than mine because it:

1/ Actually answers the question
2/ Gives a step-by-step answer on how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Excel for Mac or Windows is notorious for unexplained formatting.  To resolve it, you should:

1) Select the entire column

2) Right-click that column, then choose "Format Cells"

3) Choose "Custom"

4) In the "Type" field, type the following custom format:
0.00;(0.00);"";@

5) Click OK

That will show all numbers with 2 decimal places, zeros as an empty string, and text as it was entered.

More information about custom formatting is here:
https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4